# How to prevent Firefox from killing music?

Tags: music-player, firefox-for-android, pandora

I have this problem constantly when I try browsing the web while listening to music. It doesn't happen on every page, but probably somewhere around 80% of pages will cause my music to stop playing. This happens with both streaming music via the Pandora app, and when I'm playing mp3s from my SD card through the native music player app. Does anyone know of a setting, either in Firefox, one of the other apps, or universally in the Android settings, that can stop this from happening?

This is an [LG Optimus F3Q](http://www.gsmarena.com/lg_optimus_f3q-5998.php) running 4.1.2.

Comment: I doubt there is. What you're experiencing most likely is a OOM issue (low memory, so the system is freeing some for the foreground process). You didn't mention anything about your hardware and Android version, so what I wrote is a "shot in the dark" – but I wouldn't wonder if the bullet hit at the right point …

Comment: @Izzy That could be. I've added the phone and version info.

Comment: Just added the link to the specs. Hm, 1GB RAM should be sufficient. Not sure how much of that Firefox eats, though – thinking of what it does on my desktop PC, I don't trust it to be really "economical". So additional useful details would include: how many tabs are open, what else is running, have you checked memory consumption (e.g. using an app like [OS Monitor](http://www.appbrain.com/app/os-monitor/com.eolwral.osmonitor))?

Comment: @Izzy You might be onto something. This problem started to occur even between just the Pandora and Twitter apps, where I seemingly couldn't run both at the same time. I restarted my phone, started Pandora, then went into Twitter and clicked a link, which opened it in Firefox, and Pandora did not stop. I'll have to pay more attention from now on to see if memory really is the issue.

Comment: Agreed. And then don't forget to [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) once solved/proven :)